# In VS2015, how do I promote my current Solution to be the Latest Version on the server

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We made a lot of changes to our code and don't want them any more. We would like to roll back these changes to a changeset from a couple of days ago. However, we are having considerable trouble doing so. We have loaded the version we want to use. How do we go about promoting this version to be the Latest Version on the TFS server, so that our other machines can pull it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Open source control explorer, right click on the folder that you want to roll back, and choose the "roll back" option.

Comment: And next time, create a branch.